# How to simplify logic when week starts from Monday?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this code to get date in a week. But this code takes Monday as hardcoded. How to make those 4 lines flexible where its commented `"//Special check for Sunday because acc. to our business week Starts from Monday and DayOfWeek Enum starts from Sunday."`

I mean can `var` be calculated in a single line without if else condition? So that tomorrow if its decided that Sunday is Start Date, then no changes needs to be done.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime weekDate = GetWeekDate(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Friday);
        Console.WriteLine(weekDate); //prints 14-02-2014
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    private static DateTime GetWeekDate(DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        DateTime sow;
        int var = 0;
        sow = StartOfWeek(dt);

        if (dow == 0) //Special check for Sunday because acc. to our business week Starts from Monday and DayOfWeek Enum starts from Sunday.
            var = 6;
        else
            var = (int)dow - 1;

        return sow.AddDays(var);

    }

    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime dt)
    {
        int days = dt.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday; //Week Starts from Monday   

        if (days < 0)
            days += 7;

        return dt.AddDays(-1 * days).Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use First Day of Week from the globalization DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the modulo operator - `%` (also known as integral division remainder).

For example, `(7 + dow - 1) % 7` should give you the proper value.

To shift the start of week, you just have to change the value you subtract, eg. to start the week with sunday, it will be zero, to start with monday it will be 1, to start with tuesday it will be 2 (`(7 + dow - 2) % 7`) etc.

Comment: That's the remainder operator, **not** the modulo operator. They mean different things. `-2 % 5 = -2` whereas `-2 mod 5 = 3`

Comment: @Luaan: I think this has done the trick. Just checking if all is fine.

Comment: @dcastro Don't even get me started on that, it's a constant struggle trying to explain this. In any case, modulo is only defined for non-negative numbers, so your comment is also wrong. The fact that it does work in Pascal is completely irrelevant :D

Comment: @Luaan [Google Calculator](http://goo.gl/wFgf5V), Javascript, Ruby, Scala, Python and Scheme's modulo operators also allow negative dividends and negative divisors.

Comment: @dcastro That's very nice of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is depend on a constant, or even accept as parameter, the start of the business week, and use that value in your calculations instead of hard-coding it.